# Webpack stopped to load CSS variables with postcss-variables-loader

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, loader

I am migrating a webpack application based on old versions to some new ones and I am getting troubles with the load of `variable.css` which now seems not recognized anymore

```sh
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, 
currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> :root {
|   --monospace-font-family: 'Consolas', 'Inconsolata', 'Droid Sans Mono',
|     monospace;
```

```js
    "css-loader": "2.1.1",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "typescript": "4.0.3",
    "webpack": "4.30.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.0",
```

Old `webpack.config.js` used to be:

```js
      test: /\.css$/,
          exclude: /variables\.css$/,
          use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: 'style-loader',
            use: [{
                loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true, },
              },
              'postcss-loader',
            ],}),
        },
        {
          test: /variables\.css$/,
          loader: 'postcss-variables-loader?es5=1',
        }
```

Now, I am with new versions

```js
    "postcss": "^8.4.8",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2",
    "webpack": "^5.70.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.0",
```

and I had to change che `webpack.config.js` to include the new `mini-css-extract-plugin`

```js
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          exclude: /variables\.css$/,
          use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader','postcss-loader',],
        },
        {
          test: /\.variables.css$/,
          use: [ {loader: 'postcss-variables-loader?es5=1',},],
        },
```

The file `variable.css` includes some css basic var like

```
:root {
  --monospace-font-family: 'Consolas', 'Inconsolata', 'Droid Sans Mono',
    'Monaco', monospace;
}

@custom-media --small-viewport (max-width: 780px);
```

and it is imported into various `.tsx` files using just

```js
import variables from './variables.css';
```

I cannot understand if the entire structure of css and the way they are loaded must change or there's one more fix I might need.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is not the loader, but the test. A backslash was missing.

It should be:

```js
test: /\.variables\.css$/
```